# Точка с запятой

Tags: javascript

Все никак не пойму, чем отличается запись

```
var SomeVoid = function() {
    //...
}
от
var SomeVoid = function() {
    //...
};
```

Как правильно, с точкой запятой, или без? Что она значит в таком виде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно с ; ибо синтаксис таков:

```
var a = b;
```

где b

```
function() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: о, теперь я понял :) спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Точки с запятыми во многих случаях необязательны, однако их использование позволяет избежать [некоторых тонких проблем](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/111563/) и помогает упаковщикам кода, так что лучше их всё-таки ставить везде где надо. В этом конкретном примере - надо.

Comment: Сами ссылаетесь на статью жеж... Тут есть перенос строки) поэтому не обязательно

Answer (score 1):

Без разницы по-моему... В JS перенос строки заменяет точку с запятой. Единственное что - когда будете сжимать файл со скриптом, то лучше, чтобы были точки с запятой, тогда можно будет автоматически все переносы удалить.

Comment: >> В JS перенос строки заменяет точку с запятой
ух ты, первый раз слышу :) Правда чтоли ? :)

Comment: Ну вроде не встречал проблемы в этом месте)`
    <script>
        a = 3
        b = 5
        c = a + b
        alert("hello!")
        alert(c)
    </script>`

Comment: JS движок обязан при необходимости дополнять строку точкой с запятой

поэтому утверждение истинно
>>> перенос строки заменяет точку с запятой

    a = 2
    b = 3
    
    console.log( a, b )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript вот тут интересный момент обсуждается, мб об этом шла речь.

Comment: >В JS перенос строки заменяет точку с запятой

То есть, код

    $('p').css({
     'color': 'red',
     'fontSize': '20px'
    });

работать не будет? Пичаааалька. =(

Comment: инициализация объектов отрабатывает нормально... Не-надо пичалится :)

Comment: @ling: "обязан **при необходимости**"